# On Click listener is not working in View Pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am having two pages in ViewPager.In the two pages I am having buttons for which i have to make action on them.On click listener for button is working perfectly fine for second page and it is not working for first page.
Here is the activity and adapter class which i have tried

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int noofsize = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                noofsize);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.reviewpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }


}
```

And the adapter class is as follows

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements OnClickListener {
    int size;
    Activity act;
    View layout;
    TextView pagenumber;
    Button click;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, int noofsize) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        size = noofsize;
        act = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pages, null);
        pagenumber = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.pagenumber);
        pagenumber.setText("Now your in Page"+position);
        click = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.click);
        click.setOnClickListener(this);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(layout, 0);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == click) {
            Toast.makeText(act, "click event called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why is you onclick() in the adapter ? it should be in the fragments or in the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Face this same problem,In my case it solved by set click listener  in instantiateItem. You can do something like this  may it can helpful

```
click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

or

You Can try  this also

```
 click.setOnClickListener(act);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to catch button click and do something, it is better to do it in simplest possible way...
*less code is better!*
here we go;
inside your layout.xml of the button component (or whatever is the component) should have this

```
android:onClick="onClick_function"
```

then you can automatically catch this event inside your code, all you need just have a function with the same name

```
public void onClick_function(View v) {
// here we go!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this part is wrong:

```
if (v == click) { // What is click ?! you can't compare that
    Toast.makeText(act, "click event called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

Replace it with:

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.theIdOfTheView) {
    Toast.makeText(act, "click event called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

Use this inside the `instantiateItem`:

```
container.onClickListener();
```

Comment: Do you get the Toast message if you remove the `if` statement ?